# QuickEdit not appearing

Tags: 8, entities

I have enabled QuickEdit but not seeing its functionality appear anywhere.

Here is my `node--type.html.twig`:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'node',
    'node--type-' ~ node.bundle|clean_class,
    node.isPromoted() ? 'node--promoted',
    node.isSticky() ? 'node--sticky',
    not node.isPublished() ? 'node--unpublished',
    view_mode ? 'node--view-mode-' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
  ]
%}

<article{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}{{ title_suffix }}

  <div class="hl__base-template__main-content">
    <div class="hl__base-template__page-content hl__base-template__page-content--full">

      {% if node.field_image_position.value == 'below' %}
        <div class="hl__story-template__main-image">
          {{ content.field_summary_image }}
        </div>
      {% endif %}

      {{ content|without('field_story_subject', 'field_summary_image') }}

      {% if node.field_story_subject.value is not empty %}
        <section class="hl__labeled-list">
          <div class="hl__labeled-list__container">
            <div class="hl__labeled-list__label">Tags:</div>
            {{ content.field_story_subject }}
          </div>
        </section>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Here is my body field twig, for example:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'hl__rich-text'
  ]
%}

{% for item in items %}
  <section{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>{{ item.content }}</section>
{% endfor %}
```

`{{ attributes }}` in neither case seem to carry the things that attach quickedit to tags. I am using Stable as the base theme - what is missing here?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong in the templates when they output `{{ attributes }}`. If attributes don't contain any quickedit data, then the problem must be somewhere else. The most obvious is, has the user the permission to use quickedit?

Comment: I am as user 1 right now

Comment: The second condition (and the last), is the entity the latest revision? Unlikely though this is the cause, so there is probably some debugging necessary to see what is happening in the attributes variable of entity and field.

Comment: Your code looks fine, perhaps quick edit is not working at all. To test my theory, change to Bartik theme and see if the problem occurs there too. If so, try uninstalling and enabling the quick edit module.

Comment: What I did not know is that apparently you can only use it in unpublished or draft state of a node, not published.